# Reading in images in a folder withouth knowing the exact names

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a folder full of images. I want to use them to compute the optical flow with OpenCV. What is a good cross-platform way to read in all the images without having to know the exact file names?

I could rename the images to 1.png, 2.png, and so on, if that helps.

Comment: check out boost.filesystem

Comment: @user1095108: Looks good, but I'd prefer a way without more external libraries.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: @PiotrNycz that only works for Windows, right?

Comment: cross platform today means using external libraries. boost.filesystem v3 should be part of the standard soon, so you'd be on the safe side by using it today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a hidden gem in core/utility.hpp:

```
void glob(String pattern, std::vector<String>& result, bool recursive = false);
```

(takes a dir or similar, returns a vector of filenames)

Comment: That's part of OpenCV, right? That would be awesome!

Comment: Where is that core/utility.hpp? STL? Boost? Linux? Windows?

Comment: yes, opencv (sorry, question lost the opencv tag while writing this)

Comment: Note: only in OpenCV >= 2.4.9